# PHP, каким способ можно разделить массив?

Tags: php, массивы

Здравствуйте. У меня есть список городов (12 штук) и мне нужно вывести их в две колонки, в каждой по 6.

Сделала таким способом:

```
 $selectCity = "select districtName from telegramCity limit 12 offset 0";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $selectCity);

    // 1st fetch
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $data1 = [
            "text" => $row["districtName"],
            "callback_data" => json_encode(['a'=>'dist', 'p' => 1], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)
        ];

        // prepare an empty array, in case of there is no more results
        $data2 = [
            'text' => '',
            'callback_data' => json_encode(['a'=>'dist', 'p' => 1], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)
        ];

        // 2nd fetch, and put in $data2
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $data2["text"] = $row["districtName"];
        }

        // fill final array using the 2 arrays
        $buttons[] = [$data1, $data2];
    }

    $data3 = [
        "text" => ">",
        "callback_data" => "next"
    ];

   $buttons[] = [$data3];
```

Но это не очень удобно, потому что, во-первых, у меня есть пагинация и нужно дублировать большое количество кода, а во-вторых хотелось бы сделать это более автоматизированным. Чтобы, например, была переменная, которая бы значила к-во колонок, но ничего в голову не приходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: зачем Вы на бекенде решаете проблему фронтенда?

Comment: @KoVadim, потому что это TelegramBotApi, а именно — inline_buttons

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает `array_chunk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно как-то так

```
$one_row = [];
$cnt = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $one_row[$cnt] = [
        "text" => $row["districtName"],
        "callback_data" => json_encode(['a'=>'dist', 'p' => 1], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)
    ];
    $cnt++;
    //Две колонки
    if ($cnt == 2) {
        $buttons[] = $one_row;
        $one_row = [];
        $cnt = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну, почти https://sun9-5.userapi.com/c840521/v840521644/7238e/SWxfO6rUJ5A.jpg

Comment: Ну так data3 в вашем коде надо добавлять не внутри цикла, а после него. Ну и можно попробовать при сбросе $one_row делать unset

Comment: data3 здесь не имеет никакого отношения к городам. это просто стрелочка вправо, и да, я написала это после цикла. а еще код выше рабочий. я ошиблась, поместив его не в то место скрипта

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, вам нужно разделить массив, для этого можете использовать `array_chunk()`. Приведу простой пример։

```
$arrayResult = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
array_chunk($arrayResult, 2);
```

Где первый параметр это ваш исходный массив, вторым параметром вы указываете количество элементов, которые должны быть в каждом массиве. Более детально в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-chunk.php)

Comment: Как только я начала искать "как разделить массив" этот метод - первое, что мне попалось. я пыталась его использовать, но безуспешно.

Comment: И что у вас не получалось ? можете показать код который пробовали ?

Comment: @Arsen не на "сколько отдельных", а сколько в каждом отдельном будет элементов. задача разделить именно на определённое число. но это не сложно сделать, определив заранее размер каждой группы.

Comment: @Lexx918 - я об этом и писал, наверно мысль запутанной представил )) отредактировал более понятной фразой.